# 'I would have liked to see' or 'I would like to have seen'?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect

When teaching my students the usage of the verbs 'like, love, hate, prefer' with the modal verb 'would', I stumbled upon the following:

"It's a shame we didn't see Anna. I would like to have seen her again."

But my first instinct was to say: "I would have liked to see her again."

Is my version grammatically correct and if so, is there any difference in meaning between the two options?

For reference, the example sentence was taken from the 5th edition of Cambridge's Intermediate English Grammar in Use.

Comment: I would like to see her again or to have seen her again. [said "now".] I would have liked to see her again. [said about the past]. You can still like something now about a past event. [This is really an ELL question.]

Comment: [Liberman, at Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3941), covers this, citing Fowler, Garner, and Disraeli amongst others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I would like to have come" vs "I would have liked to come"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150660/i-would-like-to-have-come-vs-i-would-have-liked-to-come) (Barrie England mentions 'would have liked to have', directing us to Liberman's article.)